# QML : reload a model

Tags: qt, model, qml

I have a model I'm using in a Combobox. The model is well loaded at start. But I would like to reload it. I tried to use `Q_INVOKABLE`, but it doesn't work.
My model is defined in a header :

```
class StrategiesModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
   enum StrategiesRoles{
      textRole =Qt::UserRole + 1
   };
   explicit StrategiesModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

   // Basic functionality:
   int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

   QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

   QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

   Q_INVOKABLE bool loadStrategie();

private:
   QStringList mStrategies;
   const QString mFileName = "listStrategies.txt";
};
```

and in the source :

```
    #include "strategiesmodel.h"

StrategiesModel::StrategiesModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
    loadStrategie();
}

int StrategiesModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    // For list models only the root node (an invalid parent) should return the list's size. For all
    // other (valid) parents, rowCount() should return 0 so that it does not become a tree model.
    if (parent.isValid())
        return 0;

    // FIXME: Implement me!
    return mStrategies.size();
}

QVariant StrategiesModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    // FIXME: Implement me!
    if(role == textRole)
        return QVariant(mStrategies[index.row()]);
    else
        return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> StrategiesModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
        roles[textRole] = "text";
        return roles;
}

bool StrategiesModel::loadStrategie()
{
    mStrategies.clear();
    // Loading list from a file
}
```

In the main, the model is load like this:

```
qmlRegisterType<StrategiesModel>("Strategies", 1, 0, "StrategiesModel");
```

But when I tried to reload the model, it fails:

```
strategies.model: StrategiesModel {} // First load works
strategies.textRole: "text"


refresh.onClicked: function(){
    StrategiesModel.loadStrategie(); // Fail
}
```

I got this error :

```
TypeError: Property 'loadStrategie' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

How can I made my function accessible?

Thanks in adavance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the name of the class you are not accessing an object so you can not use any method, what you can do is use the existent object through its `id`:

```
strategies.model: StrategiesModel{ id: some_model} // First load works
strategies.textRole: "text"

refresh.onClicked: function(){
    some_model.loadStrategie();
}
```

According to what I check the `loadStrategie` loads new data to the model, so that the view is notified you must use `beginResetModel()` before the change and `endResetModel()` after making the changes.

***.cpp**

```
bool StrategiesModel::loadStrategie()
{
    beginResetModel();
    mStrategies.clear();
    ...
    // Loading list from a file
    ...
    endResetModel();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! The C++ reloads the file and ```mStrategies``` is well filled. But there is still a problem. The list in the Combo box keeps old values.  But the stranger thing is when I select a value (with the old label in the list), once selected, the new label appears!
The expanded list has old values, but each selected value is right.

Comment: It was that. Thanks a lot!!